# Why does this malloc wrapper do this to the size of the requested memory? size = (size + 3) & ~3;

Tags: c

I'm looking through DOOM source code and I found [this](https://github.com/id-Software/DOOM/blob/master/linuxdoom-1.10/z_zone.c#L211) line.

```
void *
Z_Malloc
        (int size,
         int tag,
         void *user) {
    int extra;
    memblock_t *start;
    memblock_t *rover;
    memblock_t *newblock;
    memblock_t *base;

    size = (size + 3) & ~3; // Why is it doing this?
...
```

I see `sizeof` used a lot to create byte offsets, but I've never seen this.

I understand the caller of this function wants some memory allocated, but I'm at a loss why it would manipulate the `size` like this.

What is it doing?

Comment: This rounds up `size` to a multiple of 4, but that doesn't answer why only what

Comment: It was probably done for performance reasons, aligning blocks  for faster access probably.

Comment: It is for rounding up the size.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`size = (size+3) & ~3` rounds the size up to the nearest multiple of 4.

It does this so that all blocks are a multiple of 4 bytes long and every block starts at an address that is a multiple of 4.

This is necessary so that the placement of ints and pointers inside the block can be aligned to fit into single memory words, which makes accessing them more efficient.  Some processors actually require it.

To see how the rounding works, lets say that *size = 4x-a*, where *0 <= a <= 3*.  We have:

*size+3 = 4x + (3-a)*, where *3-a* is also between *0* and *3*.

*~3* is a bit mask that includes all bits except *2<sup>0</sup>* and *2<sup>1</sup>*, so the *&* operation will leave just the multiple of 4:

*(size+3)&~3 = 4x*

Comment: Hey Matt, thanks for the answer! I am pretty sure that OP has no idea how the rounding is done. I suggest you give an example! ;)

Comment: This means the code *assumes* a target machine with integers and pointers that are four bytes (or aligned on 4-byte boundaries).    Not all target machines have that.  On machines with integers or pointers smaller than four bytes, it will offer little performance advantage and consume more memory.   On machines with integers or pointers larger than four bytes, it will probably not give intended benefits (e.g. aligning blocks for faster access).

Comment: @Peter, right.  The OP says this code is from the DOOM source, so it's presumably 80x86-specific

Answer (score 2):

If you run this it will be obvious:

```
for(int i=0; i<30; i++)
    printf("%d ", (i+3) & ~3);
```

Output:

```
0 4 4 4 4 8 8 8 8 12 12 12 12 16 16 16 16 20 20 20 20 24 24 24 24 28 28 28 28 32
```

It rounds up to nearest 4.

It's done like this. Performing `x = x & ~3` will set the two least significant bits of `x` to zero. If we assume 8-bit numbers for simplicity, a 3 will be stored as 00000011, which means that ~3 will be 11111100, so performing a logical and with this number will set the last two bits to zero. This itself is a rounding down to nearest four, because 4 binary is 100. If you add 3 first it will be a rounding up instead.

Comment: Obvious that it rounds up, but not obvious how the rounding is done. I believe it would be nice to the OP to see an example. For instance, pick a value for `i`, and explain step by step what this expression does! ;)

Comment: Nice explanation.

Comment: @gsamaras Done. Good advice.